# Would like to use isset(empty($sc))

Tags: php

I want to use a combination of this `isset(empty($sc))` but am receiving this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EMPTY in /var/www/html/find.php on line 9

When someone posts from the form, then the `$sc` should be checked if empty only if the form has been submitted.

Comment: On the subject, you problem is that `isset` function needs a variable as an argument, not a result of a function.

Comment: Empty itself does isset on that var and then checks ifi it's empry or not, so you should just use empty($csc)

Comment: **Note:** Because [this](http://php.net/empty) is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable functions](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. `isset(empty(…))` does not make any sense. Maybe you meant something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if(empty($_POSt['sc'])) echo 'sc is empty';
  else echo 'sc is non-empty';
} else {
  echo '$_POST[\'submit\'] is not set';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code kind of doesn't make sense.

It seems that your `$sc` variable is global var, right ?

Then better code would be:

```
if (isset($sc) && !empty($sc)) {
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `empty()` function returns a boolean depending on whether a variable is empty or not. you can't run `isset()` on a scalar value (true or false, or a string, number, char or any other primitive type), you need to run it against a variable.

this works:

```
$var = 'hello';
isset($var);
```

returns **true**

this **WONT** work:

```
isset('hello');
```

this is equivalent to what you are doing.

Comment: **Note:** Because [this](http://php.net/empty) is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable functions](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use isset on a function.

Isset is used to detect if the variable passed into the function really exists or not with the subtle twist that an existing variable with NULL will still be considered unset.

Passing a function return to isset is incorrect as it is obviously always unset, it's a transitory state.

What you want to do is:

```
if(!isset($sc) || empty($sc)){ $errors[] = 'Missing SC'; }
```

Happy coding

Comment: **Note:** Because [this](http://php.net/empty) is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable functions](http://php.net/functions.variable-functions)